Finding the offset of a named range in a VBA function

Hello. This is my first post on stack overflow, so I'm not sure how the format works here.
I have a excel sheet of employees that contains their full name, department, hiring date, and hourly wage.
The highlighted area in the sheet is a named range that I used in VBA.
Here is my code.
Function hoursOfEmployee(nameOfPerson As String, dataRange As Range)

    For Each Value In dataRange
        If Value = nameOfPerson Then
            
            hoursOfEmployee = Range(dataRange).Offset(0, 3).Select
              
        End If
        
    Next Value
                        
End Function

I'm trying to find the hourly wage of an employee based on their name. The function takes in two parameters: The name of the person I'm looking for, and the named range to look in for their name and hourly rate. Once I have the range, I want to loop through each value in the range until it equals the 'nameOfPerson' parameter. If the values match, I want the function to return the cell that is 3 columns to the right of the current cell.
In Excel, I used the formula:
=hoursOfEmployee(A1,DataSource)
where A1 is the name "Straker, Jason", and "DataSource" is the named range.
When I run the function, I get this error message: #VALUE!
Any help would be appreciated.

Definitely don't want .Select. Range(dataRange) should likely be Value. Could use a an Exit For before the End If. Side note: it does feel like  you're recreating VLOOKUP (or XLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.)

Don't want to select in a function. And you are offsetting from DataRange when you want to offset from the found value range (if found!)

Yes, this per comment from BigBen, agree that this may be much better without vba.
